# coarser/finer relation for relative topology and norm topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose $p\in [1, \infty]$. Show the relative topology on $l^p(\mathbb{R})$ induced from the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}= \Pi_{l=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}$ is coarser than the $p$-norm topology on $l^p(\mathbb{R})$, but the relative topology on $l^p(\mathbb{R})$induced by the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is finer than the $p$-norm topology on $l^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Attempt:
I know that any basic open set $U$ in the relative product space is an union of the form $\Pi_{i=1}^{\infty} O_i$, where $O_i \in \mathbb{R}$. So it's like a box. And it's clear geometrically that we can always find a $p$-ball $B(x,r)$ such that it's contained in $U$ for every $x\in U$. But I'm not sure how to construct such $r$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic open set containing a point $x_0$ in the product topology is of the form $\{x: |p_1(x)-p_1(x_0)| <r_1, ...., |p_N(x)-p_N(x_0)|<r_N\}$ where $p_1,p_2,..$ are the projection maps. If $r=\min \{r_1,r_2,..,r_N\}$ then the ball of radius $r$ in $\ell^{p}$ around $x_0$ is contained in this basic neighborhood. This proves the first part.

Consider any ball $B(x_0,r)$ in $\ell^{p}$. $\{x: |p_i(x)-p_i(x_0)|<\frac r {2^{i/p}} \forall i\}$ is an open set containing $x_0$ in the Box topology which is contained in $B(x_0,r)$ .

Comment: Hi, for the first part, where did you get $N$? (I'm assuming that N is some finite number?) Is it the cardinality of the basis? Also, what are the $p_i$'s projecting? Thanks!

Comment: $N$ is some positive integer. Every basic neighborhood of $x_0$ has this form for some $N$ and some $r_i$'s. $p_i(x_1,x_2,...)=x_i$.  @cciirrcclllee

Comment: For the second part, the reason why we get that $p$-norm topology $\subseteq$ relative topology induced by box topology, is it because $B_{x_0}(r)=  \cup_{x \in B(x_0,r)} U_x$, where $U_x $ is the set you defined in the second line? Thanks!

Comment: @cciirrcclllee Yes, that is correct.